# InvalidProgramException in DataContext constructor

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, linq-to-sql, datacontext, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using LINQ to SQL to connect to a local database on Windows Phone 8.1. When I try to instantiate my DataContext I get a InvalidProgramException on the constructor line. My DataContext looks like this:

```
public class AppDataContext : DataContext
{
    public AppDataContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
    }
}
```

The connection string I'm using is the one that I got from [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286405%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

```
var db = new AppDataContext("Data Source=isostore:/MyDatabase.sdf");
```

I've looked through the internet and I didn't find anything related to Windows Phone 8.1. **This same code is working fine on Windows Phone 8.**

I think that the problem here is my connection string. Maybe something has changed with the 8.1 SDK?

Comment: Is this a `Silverlight` app or a `Universal` app? The `isostore:/` part of the path isn't valid for the latter.

Comment: It's a Windows Phone Store App, no Silverlight.

Comment: It seems that this exception is thrown independently of the connection string I'm using.

Comment: For Universal Apps you need to use a [ms-appdata://](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj655406.aspx#ms_appdata) uri scheme.

Comment: "Data Source=ms-appdata://MyDatabase.sdf" didn't work.

Comment: If it's included as a resource, rather than as content, you need to use the other uri schemes. Try spend a few minutes reading the documentation.

Comment: I don't have a database file. It's first created when I call `db.CreateDatabase()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue.  I actually had to manually import the System.Data.Linq.dll file as a reference from the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK folder.  I'm not sure why that .dll is there because [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f7352694-31a8-4c6f-9fd4-ce49661c51cb/cant-find-systemdatalinq-or-microsoftphonedatalinq-in-a-windows-phone-81-project?forum=wpdevelop) explains that the local databases are no longer available in Windows Phone 8.1.  Looks like I'm switching to SQLite.

Comment: I didn't know that. Is it possible to use LINQ to SQL along with SQLite?

Comment: Old thread now, but to my knowledge this won't work as expected out-of-the-box with SQLite.  [DBLinq](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/) I believe provides some of that functionality, although most SQLite implementations will provide enough basic querying features to make the calls efficient and then you can always use LINQ if needed once the data gets returned.

Comment: Thank you John. At that time I ended up using just SQLite. The good part about it is that it comes with an ORM, so it feels just like LINQ to SQL.